# How do I increase session timeout with W.I.F / SAML tokens / FedAuth cookie

Tags: wif

I think the default timeout is something like every half hour.

I'd like to change this to 2 weeks. Anyone got any ideas?

Is this done usually from the STS side or the client side? Is forms authentication getting in the way too, or is that now irrelevant?

Comment: You could solve the problem? I hope your answer!

Comment: Did you solve this, got the same issue.

Comment: No... I just came back to try figure it out... I added  persistentSessionLifetime="60" and it didn't do anything... trying  persistentSessionLifetime="60.00:00" now...

Answer (score 17):

I just fixed this myself, persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects needs to be enabled on the RP

In your web.config you need:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation
            persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
        <cookieHandler 
          persistentSessionLifetime="60.0:0:0" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The timeout for the FedAuth token may be managed in the web.config for the claims-aware application.  An example with documentation may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638729.aspx).  Keep in mind, though, that there is the STS-side of the coin and that the timeout may need to be increased there as well to prevent the user from having to sign-in again when moving from one application to another after an extended period.

Comment: Thanks for posting that link. I must have stared at it more than 20 times and tried everything - still have not found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie is timing out you can also look at using sliding sessions in your WIF application.

This means that the cookie will continue to be re-established while the user is "using" the application.

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/05/08/sliding-sessions-for-wif-4-5/

Answer (score 0):

The description about persistentSessionLifetime in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568663.aspx) is not true. For example, if you set it to 1.6:13:45.0, the cookie will expire after 30 hours (1 day + 6 hours) 13 minutes and 45 seconds +/- the maximumClockSkew from <identityConfiguration>. So the description from MSDN should be like the one from TimeSpan: [-]d.hh:mm:ss.ff. I hope Microsoft changes the wrong description.