# Claims-based Authentication Token Expiry

Tags: wif, adfs

Researching I found how to change the life of a token by using the powershell command

set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust-TargetName "your app display name Relying party in ADFS trust"-
TokenLifetime "value in minutes"

My problem is that once time passes I need to log out,I do not know if this is possible,  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The token lifetime and your session lifetime are two different things. If you want automatic log out you can do it by configuring the session cookie lifetime at your relying party:

[Windows Identity Foundation - relying party session security token lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972005/windows-identity-foundation-relying-party-session-security-token-lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

Good overview here:

[ADFS 2.0 time out and relation between Freshness Value,TokenLifetime and WebSSOLifetime parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867613/adfs-2-0-time-out-and-relation-between-freshness-value-tokenlifetime-and-webssol/15646787#15646787).

Essentially, there are two parameters:

**WebSSOLifetime:**

This is a server wide setting which applies to all the RP’s (Relying Party).

**TokenLifetime:**

This is a RP level setting which applies to a particular RP. It will not affect other RP’s configured in the ADFS server.

Key point:

In order to prompt a user to re-authenticate, we require WebSSOLifetime to be lower than the TokenLifetime.

Answer (score 0):

This almost sounds like a duplicate of my question

[How to set the timeout properly when federating with the ADFS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130999/how-to-set-the-timeout-properly-when-federating-with-the-adfs-2-0)

What I had to do was to have a local event handler that deletes the cookie but also make sure that ADFS doesn't automatically renew thr session.