# How to increase Azure ACS login timeout

Tags: acs

The Azure Training Kit includes a lab titled "IntroToACS2". In it, you create a WebRole and enable ACS so that you can login using your Google, Live, or Yahoo id. After logging in, if I wait 10 minutes or so and then refresh the page, I'm redirected back to the login page.

How can I increase the Azure ACS login timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I found:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185906.aspx#BKMK_5

> Token Lifetime
>
> The Token lifetime property allows you to specify the amount of time for a security token issued by ACS to the relying party application to remain valid. By default, in ACS, this value is set to 10 minutes (600 seconds). In ACS, this value must be greater than zero but less than or equal to 24 hours (86400 seconds).

[image]

While the maximum lifetime is 24 hours it's possible to automatically renew the ACS token by adding the following 6 lines of code in ShowSigninPage function, just before the existing loop over identityProviders:

```
for (var i in identityProviders) {
    if (cookieName !== null && cookieName == identityProviders[i].Name) {
        window.location = identityProviders[i].LoginUrl;
        return null;
    } }

// Loop through the identity providers for (var i in identityProviders) {
...
```

For more info the automatic renewal approach see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuresecurity/thread/0430c4aa-ab10-4a72-b115-91b2600bfcd0

Comment: Go read the responses to that msdn thread. There are numerous people giving that guy the same advice as I just gave you =)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is to increase your application's session lifetime, and **not** the ACS issued token lifetime.

[How do I increase session timeout with W.I.F / SAML tokens / FedAuth cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452488/how-do-i-increase-session-timeout-with-w-i-f-saml-tokens-fedauth-cookie)