# WIF login expires prematurely in IE9

Tags: asp.net, wif

I have created an STS and a relying website that is able to authenticate using the STS via WIF. In all browsers but IE9 this works well. In IE9, after logging in and using the relying website for about 5 minutes (not consistent, but usually happens after 5 to 10 minutes) the user is redirected back to the STS to sign in again.

However, the user is not really signed out of the STS. If the user simply refreshes the sign in page of the STS, a new tab opens and takes them back to the relying website.

I am very puzzled by this behavior, and can only reproduce it in IE9. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your session cookie is expiring too early. Can you check your site's web.config and see what persistentSessionLifetime you have set in the cookie handler (if any)?

This post has some detail:

[How do I increase session timeout with W.I.F / SAML tokens / FedAuth cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452488/how-do-i-increase-session-timeout-with-w-i-f-saml-tokens-fedauth-cookie)

Comment: By that you mean my relying party's session cookie is expiring too early and not the STS session correct?

Comment: According to your description, yes that seems to be what's happening.

Comment: I updated my web.config based on the example from the question, but the problem still occurs. It actually gets worse with those settings, the user is fully logged out of the STS as well as the relying site and must log in again to be returned to the relying party.